# C - UNIX commands in program

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to create a program where it would count the number of directories, or the number of readable/writable/executable files. The user would input only the name of the author and the letters "d", "r", "w", or "x". I tried to directly call "ls -l" in my program but that caused an error. How do you call UNIX commands within a C program?

Comment: look into `system()`

Comment: Although [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) 'works', you'd have to manufacture the command line carefully; there's no way for the launching program to filter the output (in the ordinary course of events). You might need to use POSIX functions [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html), or maybe [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) and [`execvp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) and related functions (`pipe()`, `dup2()`, …).

Comment: You might also want to investigate POSIX functions [`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html),
[`opendir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/opendir.html),
[`readdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html),
[`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html).

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to directly call "ls -l" in my program but that caused an error. How do you call UNIX commands within a C program?

You can se `system` in your C program, for example:

```
system( "ls -l" );
```

For that to work, you'll also need to `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: I think the program output is necessary in this case too.

Comment: In that case use `popen`

Answer (score 0):

Using the find command might work better, you could count directories with the command "find . -t d | wc -l" and do something similar for files with the appropriate flags.